# Cant get clicked div using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to change the background color of the clicked div that are menuitems.

here is my code:

```
<div id="leftpanel">
 <h4>Menu</h4>
 <div id="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked('Inicio');">Inicio</div>
 <div id="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked('Ventas');">Ventas</div>
 <div id="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked('Consultas');">Consultas</div>
 <div id="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked('Notas');">Notas</div>
 <div id="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked('Ingreso de mercaderia');">Ingreso de mercaderia</div>
 <div id="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked('Ingreso de categoria');">Ingreso de categoria</div>               
 <div id="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked('salir');">salir</div>

</div>
```

and the .js file

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
 $("#menuitem").click(function()    {
 $(this).css("background-color","red");     
});
});
```

Comment: `id`'s must be unique. use `class` instead of using `id`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs must be unique in HTML. Consider using class names instead:

```
<div id="leftpanel">
 <h4>Menu</h4>
 <div class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked('Inicio');">Inicio</div>
 <div class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked('Ventas');">Ventas</div>
 <div class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked('Consultas');">Consultas</div>
 <div class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked('Notas');">Notas</div>
 <div class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked('Ingreso de mercaderia');">Ingreso de mercaderia</div>
 <div class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked('Ingreso de categoria');">Ingreso de categoria</div>               
 <div class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked('salir');">salir</div>

</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
 $(".menuitem").click(function()    {
 $(this).css("background-color","red");     
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `class` instead of `id`'s

Something like this:

```
<div id="leftpanel">
    <h4>Menu</h4>
    <div class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked($(this).text());">Inicio</div>
    <div class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked($(this).text());">Ventas</div>
    <div class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked($(this).text());">Consultas</div>
    <div class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked($(this).text());">Notas</div>
    <div class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked($(this).text());">Ingreso de mercaderia</div>
    <div class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked($(this).text());">Ingreso de categoria</div>
    <div class="menuitem" onclick="menuItemClicked($(this).text());">salir</div>
</div>
```

and then,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menuitem").click(function(){
       $(this).css("background-color","red");     
    });
});
```

Comment: In this code `menuItemClicked` has been removed. You can add this by passing the value of `this` using `.text()`: `menuItemClicked($(this).text());`

Comment: @Broxzier why `.text()` ?  Sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: @Mr_Green Because the innerHTML is also the parameter.

Comment: @Broxzier no need of triggering `menuItemClicked` function. as I am calling the click event through jQuery. That's why I haven't mentioned `menuItemClicked` function in HTML code.

Comment: @Mr_Green We don't know what else `menuItemClicked` does, it is not even said it does anything with the background color.

Comment: @Broxzier yup I got you now. sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: But still the OP is calling the same event twice which is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that others have said about HTML, Id, Class and all, You should implement that and,

Just add this script to get what you need

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menuitem").click(function () {
        $(".menuitem").css("background-color", "");
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    });
});
```

`$(".menuitem").css("background-color", "");` extra line would clean previously red items.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tJKD/)**